# How to make functions auto run every 5 minutes?

Tags: python, multithreading, loops

I wrote proxy checker and I need to automate checking for every 5 minutes. My `while True` loop skips the functions. When I have first iteration - functions are running, but with next iterations they are skipped, just printing *START!!!!!!* and *END----* in my console.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        print("START!!!!!!!!!!")
        http_proxy_check()
        save_proxy('http')
        print("END------------------")
        time.sleep(2)
```

***http_proxy_check function:***

```
def http_proxy_check():
    for proxy in http_proxyList:
        print(f"Checking {http_proxyList.index(proxy)} of {len(http_proxyList)} element")
        thread = Thread(target=checkIp_http,args=(proxy.strip(), ))
        if len(threads)<=1200 :
            thread.start()
            threads.append(thread)
        else:
            threads.clear()

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
```

Comment: The way you're handling threads is highly dubious. If you have up to 1,200 concurrent threads it's unlikely that they'll finish their work in 2 seconds (your sleep time). You should take a look at ThreadPoolExecutor in concurrent.futures and consider using the executor's *map()* functionality. You also need to consider how to manage restarting the process if an iteration of the proxy list takes longer than the scheduled interval

Answer (score 0):

You are directly trying to run subthreads. Why are you not using multiprocess?

Also you can try to "timeloop" library for periodic tasks;
https://pypi.org/project/timeloop/

```bash
pip install timeloop
```

```py
import time

from timeloop import Timeloop
from datetime import timedelta

tl = Timeloop()

@tl.job(interval=timedelta(minutes=5))
def sample_job_every_5m():
    print "5m job current time : {}".format(time.ctime())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:   # infinite loop
    your_code_that_process()   # put your code that do stuff once and exit
    time.sleep(5*60)  # 300 seconds of sleeping, make it wait 300sec
    if check_for_abort_if_so_break():  # you can make flag that you trigger on error or by input 
                                       # so you can exit out of infinite loop
        break  # exit infinite loop (not so infinite anymore)
```

Comment: @HedgeHog i added extra commend to code, so its more readable and hope it will help